# How to keep Horizontal , Vertical Axis titles & Names at Horizontal Axis for BarChart

Tags: flutter, bar-chart

I am using BarChart to display data based on the month, value. Here I am able to display BarChart with X,Y Axis with numeric values.

I want to display Month names along Horizontal axis instead of Month numbers.

```
Row(
  children: [
    const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
    MyVerticalText('Rupees   '),
    Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 330,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
      //color: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
      child: BarChart(BarChartData(
          borderData: FlBorderData(
              border: const Border(
            top: BorderSide.none,
            right: BorderSide.none,
            left: BorderSide(width: 1),
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 1),
          )),
          groupsSpace: 10,
          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            rightTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
            topTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
          ),
          // add bars
          barGroups: _reportModel.data!
              .map((reportData) => BarChartGroupData(
                      x: reportData.month ?? 0,
                      barRods: [
                        BarChartRodData(
                            toY: reportData.value
                                    ?.toDouble() ??
                                0,
                            width: 15,
                            color: Colors.blue),
                      ]))
              .toList())),
    ),
  ],
),
Text(
  'Month(s)',
  style:
      TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
//const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
Text(
  'Your Monthly Payments',
  style:
      TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
```

Here I want to display String instead of Integer

Reference : `x: reportData.month like 1,2,3 ,` to `x: reportData.monthName like Jan, Feb, Mar,`

Also I want to add Horizontal & Vertical titles like Rupees (Vertical) & Months (Horizontal)

[image: Current BarChart screen for reference]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your solution.

So, this is the output of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://i.postimg.cc/bYCKyk8G/Screenshot-2023-08-25-at-9-15-10-PM.png)

Source code:

```
class ChartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChartScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChartScreen> createState() => _ChartScreenState();
}

class _ChartScreenState extends State<ChartScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: BarChart(
              BarChartData(
                borderData: FlBorderData(
                  border: const Border(
                    left: BorderSide(),
                    bottom: BorderSide(),
                  ),
                ),
                groupsSpace: 10,
                gridData: const FlGridData(
                  verticalInterval: 1,
                  horizontalInterval: 1,
                ),
                titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                  rightTitles: const AxisTitles(),
                  topTitles: const AxisTitles(),
                  bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                    sideTitles: SideTitles(
                      showTitles: true,
                      reservedSize: 30,
                      getTitlesWidget: bottomTitleWidgets,
                      interval: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                barGroups: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                    .map(
                      (int reportData) => BarChartGroupData(
                        x: reportData,
                        barRods: <BarChartRodData>[
                          BarChartRodData(
                            toY: reportData.toDouble(),
                            width: 15,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const TextStyle style = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 10,
    );
    Widget text;
    switch (value.toInt()) {
      case 1:
        text = const Text("JAN", style: style);
        break;
      case 2:
        text = const Text("FEB", style: style);
        break;
      case 3:
        text = const Text("MAR", style: style);
        break;
      case 4:
        text = const Text("APR", style: style);
        break;
      case 5:
        text = const Text("MAY", style: style);
        break;
      case 6:
        text = const Text("JUN", style: style);
        break;
      case 7:
        text = const Text("JUL", style: style);
        break;
      case 8:
        text = const Text("AUG", style: style);
        break;
      case 9:
        text = const Text("SEP", style: style);
        break;
      case 10:
        text = const Text("OCT", style: style);
        break;
      case 11:
        text = const Text("NOV", style: style);
        break;
      case 12:
        text = const Text("DEC", style: style);
        break;
      default:
        text = const Text("", style: style);
        break;
    }

    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      child: text,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What about Horizontal & Vertical titles? Any work around ? @Dharam Budh

Comment: Okay, I did what I understood. Now, could you please explain more about what you need exactly? Which things are still remaining?